# How to import a Postgres 9.4 extension in windows?

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to import/install a Postgres extension to my Postgres 9.4 on windows. The extension is this:
https://pt.osdn.net/projects/pghintplan/releases/p14475

The first doubt I have is that this is a rpm file, so I believe it is target to Linux. I dont have sure if I can simply unzip it and install it on my windows machine. After unzip it I get this folder structure:

usr\pgsql-9.4\lib
inside this file: pg_hint_plan.so
usr\pgsql-9.4\share\extension\
a lot of sql files and a control file.

In my Postgres install I do have a lib and share folders. And inside the share\extension folder I have many sql + control files. However, inside the lib file I have dll and not ".so" files.

Thus this means this extension is not compiled to be used on windows? Or it should be installed using any other method?

ps: I have contrib package installed, as Im able to execute: SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions; Does this help?

thank you!

Comment: The postgresql developers are of the opinion that the planner should be improved instead if hinted at.  try a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Linux executables (which this RPM doubtless contains) on Windows.

You will have to build the extension yourself. That means to install a C compiler like Microsoft Visual C. You need software development skills, because building an extension on Windows is not always easy. You should ask the maintainers of the extension if Windows is a supported target at all; maybe they can assist you with the building process.

You might need somebody who is more skilled with computers than you are (no offense meant, but if you don't know the difference between Linux and Windows...).

In addition, you should definitely *not* use PostgreSQL 9.4. It is old and out of support. Use v12.